# @FetchRequest not dynamically updating view

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, fetchrequest

I am using the below fuucntion to fetch Data and dispaly it. The problem is the view updates but does not sort according to id's (as I read online, @FetchRequest doesnt update view dynamically). It is only when I refresh my view, I see the sorting corrected. Is there any way out so that my view updates dynamically.

```
@FetchRequest (entity: ChatData.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "id",      ascending: true)])
var chatData : FetchedResults <ChatData>

ScrollView {
    VStack{
        ForEach(chatData, id: \.self) { message in
            if message.role != "system" {
                ChatCell(message: message.content ?? "", user: message.role ?? "")
            }
        }
    }//:VStack
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .listStyle(.plain)
}//:ScrollView
```

Comment: All CoreData objects need to be wrapped with ObservedObject at every level to see changes you can do this with subviews.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Where should I add observedObject and observable?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `id` for an attribute name because that is used for the `Identifiable` protocol you'll need to rename it to something else like `uid`, and here is an improvement to the code using a predicate instead of an `if`:

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(key: "uid", ascending: true)],
                    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "role != %@", "system"))
var chatData : FetchedResults <ChatData>

ScrollView {
    VStack{
        ForEach(chatData) { message in
            ChatCell(message: message.content ?? "", user: message.role ?? "")
        }
    }//:VStack
    .padding(.horizontal)
    .listStyle(.plain)
}//:ScrollView
```